# Customize WooCommerce Product Images (Placement and size)

Tags: loop, images, plugins, thumbnails

so I'm having trouble trying to re-size my product thumbnail images. The site can be seen here : http://www.seekoften.com/eCommerce .

I'd like the single-product page to have **square** thumbnails below the large featured image, but I also want the thumbnails that show in the cart (both on the page, and the sidebar cart widget ), to be vertically oriented, like the featured images, just a scaled down version of it. What files and which loops or lines of code should I look at, and how do I go about accomplishing this ?

As a secondary question, how can I customize the output so that it shows the product images that you have in your cart, but on the checkout page ( again, preferably the large vertically oriented image ) ?

For what it's worth, I have plugins like regenerate Thumbnails and Simple Image Sizes

I would greatly appreciate any help that anybody is willing to offer, and would like to thank you all in advance for reading this at all :)

Cheers,

Sincerely,

Chris "Fawkz" Coffin

Comment: What have you tried to make this work? This is a place to get help with your code, not a place to ask someone to write code for you for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file responsible for generating the sidebar cart is mini-cart.php and is located in

```
woocommerce/templates/cart/mini-cart.php
```

What you do is you copy that file and paste it into

```
YOURTHEMEFOLDER/woocommerce/cart/mini-cart.php
```

Open up that file and edit line 40 where it contains

```
<?php echo $_product->get_image(); ?>`
```

Change that to

```
<?php echo $_product->get_image( array( 50, 80 ) ); ?>
```

50 is the width and 80 is the height.  Change it to whatever size you want.

After you have done that make sure to clear your cache and restart your browser as sometimes the mini cart gets cached.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that! I have yet to try it (because I'm out of office, and don't really feel like working pro-bono tonight) but will do it tomorrow first thing. I appreciate the detailed response very much.

Do you have any insight on making the product's featured images ( and possibly some details )  show up on the Checkout page ?

Comment: Please post another topic for your other questions and I will see how I can  help.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it :)

You can find my revised follow-up question here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111079/woocommerce-checkout-page-customization