# WooCommerce Checkout page customization

Tags: customization, plugins

I'd like some help with customizing the functionality of my WooCommerce driven site. The link can be found here: http://seekoften.com/eCommerce/checkout

How can I customize the output so that it shows the product images that you have in your cart, but on the checkout page ?

Also, as a side note to this question, what files / lines of code might I want to look at if I'd like to add another drop-down to the checkout form. Also, if I'd like to change the wording of "select a state" to be "select a province" ?

Thanks in advance for your help, as you guys have always aided me in my web-ventures.

Sincerely,

Chris Coffin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the product image to the checkout review order page, you want to add the following into your functions.php file of your theme.

```
function my_add_order_review_product_image( $product, $product_obj ) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id( $product_obj->post->ID ), 'shop_thumbnail' );

    return $image . $product;
}

 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_product_title', 'my_add_order_review_product_image', 10, 2 );
```

This is utilizing the filter hook that is present in order reviews file template of WooCommerce.

Comment: Thank you so much for that, do you think you can help me figure out the 2nd part of the question ? Regarding adding a drop-down to the checkout page, and changing the wording of one of the drop-downs.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Again, please post different questions in different posts.  Also please accept the answers that we post if it solves your issue.  I asked you about that on your other question as well...

Comment: How can I "accept answers" if it solves the issue ? Also, for what it's worth, I added the code to my functions.php file of the child theme, and it did NOT solve the issue.

Comment: I made a slight edit to the code...can you test it again?

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! However, I'll have to fix the display of the images, they're much too square, where I want them vertically oriented. How might I be able to change that ? Also, can I change the spacing before / after the table ?

And again, how do I mark a question as solved ?

Comment: Click the checkmark inbetween the up/down arrows next to the post

Comment: Alright! Thanks! Do you think you can help me figure out the 2nd part of my post ? Or do you want me to create an independent thread for it ?

Comment: Yes please post another question

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111249/woocommerce-checkout-page-custom-coding

Answer (score 0):

You can override your templates, which may help you solve some of your problem, see the link below.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Thanks, I've already read extensively on the topic. And I have been doing that thus far. The question remains, which lines / code do I need to override and with what, to accomplish the kind of customization I'm in search of. 

Could you expand on that, while being specific to my case ?